# Bridge rectifier still putting out ac and dc, why?

Tags: rectifier, bridge

I have a bridge rectifier on my snow blower and it still producing 8 V of AC current and 24 V of DC current. Anyone know why it would still be producing both AC and DC?

Comment: The output voltage will have ripple depending on how large any smoothing cap is.

Comment: You say "still" as if you've attempted to fix it -- what have you done to it so far?

Comment: 8 volts is a voltage and not a current.

Answer (score 1):

The output is probably unfiltered pulsating DC so you'll get some kind of a measurement on the AC range of a multimeter. It doesn't really mean much. The DC measurement will be the average voltage.

The apparent AC reading is related to the AC component, adjusted to appear RMS for a sine wave (it isn't a sine wave). So it's kind of meaningless for most purposes. Diagram below from [here](https://lastminuteengineers.com/the-full-wave-bridge-rectifier/)

[image]

A quick measurement at my desk gives about 6VAC apparent AC voltage with a 17VDC average voltage (unfiltered full-wave rectified), using such a meter, which fits well with your measurement.

Answer (score 1):

Using a 20Vrms and an arbitrary load after a FW bridge with a time constant load of T=RC=20ms for 50 Hz 20Vrms , there is about 30% ripple AC of the Vdc avg.
[image]